# convert array data in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeconverter

It should not exist
`'` in my array data to draw my chart.
But my data is as follows:

```
var data=[['1','200','10'],['2','300','15'],...]
```

How do I convert it this way?

```
var data=[[1,200,10],[2,300,15],...]
```

Comment: You can parse the string-numbers like `parseInt('1',10)` this will return 1 as an integer.
But this is kind of basic knowledge. I would suggest you to dig into data types...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: You are using strings instead of integers.

You could iterate over your array and change the values one by one.
But this would just hide the issue.

The problem comes from when you created this array in the first place.
Can you provide the code where you create this array ?

Comment: I got this data from a financial site and I am trying to draw a chart with this data. Unfortunately I do not have access to the data source and I only have its output and the length of this array is more than 5000 pieces. Is there a way that I I can make this change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:**

```js
var data=[['1','200','10'],['2','300','15']];
data.forEach(function (item, index) { 
   data[index] = item.map(Number);
}); 
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the nested array and convert each element to an integer.

```
var data=[['1','200','10'],['2','300','15']]
intData = [];

data.forEach(x => {
  intData.push(x.map(s => parseInt(s)));
});
console.log(intData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your array of array of string to array of array of int:

```
let new_data = [];

data.forEach(element => {
    let buffer = [];
    element.forEach(item => {
        buffer.push(parseInt(item));
    });
    new_data.push(buffer);
});
```

Comment: why use for each instead of map?

Comment: It's just an other way to achieve the result

Answer (score -2):

To convert entire array's data type we can use map():

```
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(Number);
```

Comment: this will not work with the nested array posted in the question